# Javascript - Abort all ongoing http requests (image/video download) when user clicks on link to move to another page

Tags: javascript

To make the issue precise, here are the basic info.

I have a website with 2 buttons

- one big button at the center "preload videos" and each time the user clicks it, it makes 3 requests to download 3 AWS/cloudinary static video files.
- another button "move to next page" which brings the user to another page with similar layout (2 buttons) but associated with different videos to preload.

Here is the basic flow

- user loads the page 1 and has the big red button at the center
- user clicks First time on the "preload videos" button and this triggers in javascript the preloading, that is to say download to video1, video2, and video3
- user then clicks another time the button "preload videos" and it triggers 3 more request to preload/download video 4, video 5 and video 6.
- and so on...
- user now decides to click on the "next page" button. At the point all the clicks on "preload videos" the user had made on page 1 have not been "completely finished" , as video 5 and 6 are still being downloaded (big videos:)

I would like to know how to tell the browser to abort the download of video 5 and 6 (that had been triggered by javascript) when the user clicks on the button "next page" so that when on a device with low speed like a mobile, the user when arriving on the next page and clicking "preload videos" (some other videos 100,101 and 102) does not have his bandwidth taken/consumed/reduced by the remains of the download of video 5 and 6 from page 1.

I am pretty sure videos 5 and 6 still take bandwidth as the request have not been dropped as evidenced by the fact some console.log of page 1....show up inside the console after page 2 has itself been loaded:) another evidence is that when I look into the console, even after moving to page 2 (visually i am now in front of page 2.html) I can see video 5 and 6 show up as fully downloaded file in the Networks tabs.

I tried preventdefault or abort() or "throw error", like below, but none worked.

```
<a href="<%= deal_page_path(@next_deal) %>"
            title="move to next page"
            target="_blank"            
            rel="noreferrer"
            class="action-btn"
            onclick="abort();">Next page</a>
```

Not sure if it is important to solve this issue, but here is a simplified version of the call to preload videos when user clicks on the "preload videos button". On each new click i change "i" below so that first time it's preloading video 1 to 3, then 4 to 6 and so on.

```
$preload-videos-button.on('click', function(e) {
  preloadVideos(i,i+2)
});

preloadVideos = function(start,end) {

  console.log("Video PRELOADING launched "+ start + ' to ' + end);

  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    (function () { 
      var currentObject = VideosObject[i];//a json with all the data i need to loop
      var stId          = currentObject.id;          
      var stFilename    = currentObject.asset_filename;

      var $jqueryCurrentShellVideo = $('#content').find( $('#videoAsset-'+ stId) );

      //send to video shell the first raw data-src which *automatically*
      //generates src for video via AWS/cloudinary responsive 
      $jqueryCurrentShellVideo.data('src', s);

      //fire off a request to aws/cloudinary server with the data-src to get
      //responsive-adjusted src AND download the video when it is returned
      $.cloudinary.responsive($jqueryCurrentShellVideo);          
      $jqueryCurrentShellVideo.on('load', function(e) {                   
        $(this).attr('data-response-status', 1);            
      });          
    })();
  }
}
```

Comment: jquery : i listen to the click on the button "preload videos" and this creates request to a third party CDN (AWS). I have success/error events. I am getting inspiration also from this strategy: http://fragged.org/preloading-images-using-javascript-the-right-way-and-without-frameworks_744.html

Comment: The call is comlex but I'll try to post something understandable:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

You can repeat the same code you have posted and replace this piece of code

```
  $jqueryCurrentShellVideo.on('load', function(e) {                   
    $(this).attr('data-response-status', 1);            
  });
```

with this:

```
  $jqueryCurrentShellVideo.trigger('abort');
```

It is triggering `abort` event from [media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events).

---

The complete example will be:

```
$next-page-button.on('click', function(e) {
  abortLoading(i, i + 2)
});

abortLoading = function(start,end) {
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    (function () {
      var currentObject = VideosObject[i];
      var stId          = currentObject.id;
      var stFilename    = currentObject.asset_filename;

      var $jqueryCurrentShellVideo = $('#content').find( $('#videoAsset-'+ stId) );
      $jqueryCurrentShellVideo.trigger('abort');
    })();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want and can't abort specific videos loading when i click "preload videos". I want to abort ALL ongoing http requests when i click the other button "move to next page" which simply moves the user to another page. So i'd need to use some javascript associated, not to the image preloader liek you suggest, but with the a href "move to next page" button

Comment: and on this button, the app "does not know" what is a jqueryCurrentShellVideo, I mean, i want ALL of them aborted

Comment: can't i just target ALL ongoing http requests ?

Comment: You need to create another method, let's say `abortLoading` and call this method when you click the `next page` button.

Comment: Ok but what will be xxx in xxx.trigger('abort ´)? How can I tell the app xxx=all ongoing attempted requests /downloads ?

Comment: I've complete the example, I hope it helps.

Comment: pretty clever, you just opened a very interesting door. will try this today or tomorrow and will let you know.thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Related question: would you know how to handle it for images instead of videos ? I can't use Media events in that case

Comment: just found this: might work for images and videos:) https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/stop